# ASP.NET MVC 3 app cannot connect to SQL server 2008 instance on AWS instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services

When running an ASP.NET MVC 3 app (written in VS 2010, tested and working using SQL Server Express 2012, .NET 4.0, Windows 7 Pro) on an Amazon Web Services host (Windows Server 2008, ASP.NET 4.0 app pool, SQL Server Express 2008, IIS7), I am unable to connect to the local database on that machine, nor see any errors in connecting. I am using the following ConnectionString in Web.config:

name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=aspnet-NewWebSite-20141030101548;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Is there a modification I should make to this to make it work? I can't upgrade to SQL Server 2012 on this AWS instance. I can't even log to the Event Viewer or email errors to myself. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is pointing to a local db instance, and AWS probably doesn't support LocalDB. What you want to do is to get a DB instance that supports remote connection ( you can get one from AWS directly) and find out the connection string of that server, change yours accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I am in the process of doing that now. If I decide to stick with 2008, I'm guessing my best option would be to install 2008 on the development machine, build against that (using Entity Framework Code-First) and then deploy, adjusting the connect string accordingly. That's the backup plan at this point. I'd upvote but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation yet, but thanks again!